# How do I define a vim function on a single line?

Tags: vim

Since `|` is used to separate commands, I thought I could just do this:

```
:function! SomeFunc() | return 0 | endfunction
```

It works fine when I type it on separate lines (entering the first line causes it to prompt for the remaining lines):

```
:function! SomeFunc()
  return 0
endfunction
```

I now see this caveat at `:help :bar`:

> These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
>   followed by another Vim command:
>
> …
>
> :function

Is there any way around that?

I see where it says...

> You can also use  to separate commands in the same way as with
>   '|'.  To      insert a  use CTRL-V CTRL-J.  "^@" will be shown.

But this doesn't work either:

```
:function! SomeFunc() <NL> return 0 <NL> endfunction
```

It gives this error:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

This works if I manually type in the CTRL-V CTRL-J sequence:

```
:function! SomeFunc() ^@ return 0 ^@ endfunction
```

But that still isn't a acceptable solution because **I want to be able to simply copy and paste the `function!` command and press Enter**...

Comment: I guess I can just copy and paste the multi-line version of the function definition... But I'm still curious if there is a way to define it with one copy-and-pastable line...

Comment: Your ultimate goal is not clear to me but you can yank the function and "source" it with `:@"`.

Comment: The original problem that prompted this Q was that I found a function in a plugin that I wanted to use in my own .vim scripts/config, but it was only callable as `<SNR>104_mixedcase()`.  I wrote my own wrapper function to try to "export" it and make it easier to use from anywhere.  But it didn't work to define my new wrapper function in a script file, apparently because the <SNR> is then relative to that (wrong) file.  It did seem to work, however, if I simply pasted the function in the vim command line.  So I thought it would be nice if I could paste that as a single line/command...

Comment: Great idea, thanks!  Didn't know about :@ for sourcing the contents of registers.  That (vim registers) would work well — better than copying and pasting all the way out to the system clipboard and then back into vim.

Comment: `<SNR>104_` means "script number 104". You can locate the script with `:scriptnames` and copy the function to your vimrc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to use `exe`:

```
exe ":function! SomeFunc() \n return 0 \n endfunction"
```

The `\n` characters are interpreted as newlines by the double-quoted strings. This does mean you should be careful to escape any special sequences.

That said,

> I want to be able to simply copy and paste the function! command and press Enter...

As romainl mentioned, your ultimate goal is not clear. If this is something you do often for some reason, maybe there's a better way to get what you want. It's a good idea to describe your problem in terms of *why* you need this functionality.

Comment: Good answer.  That makes sense, and seems to work.  I've added my motivation as a comment above, but it basically has turned into just a theoretical/learning question.  I have learned several new tricks as a result, thanks!

Comment: I see, you found a useful function in a plugin, but it's script-local. Happens every once in a while. In a case like this, I'd copy the function to my local files and make it global (or autoloaded), so it's easily callable. It's copy-pasta, but if it's just a utility function, I'd say it's not a big deal.

Anyway, glad to hear you've learned new tricks, that's the value in experiments like this :).

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into this because I wanted to test out functions I copied online in a vim session before adding to my .vimrc. I tried `source` but that requires a file name.

One of the comments in the answer section says to use `:@"`. That runs whatever is in the unnamed register.

If you want to run something you copied from online, you can do `:@+`. But it won't work if you don't have vim installed with system clipboard integration.

Another method that works without clipboard integration is `:normal :<PASTE YOUR COMMAND HERE WITH YOUR SYSTEM HOTKEY>`. That runs everything in normal mode as if you were typing it yourself, each newline would continue onto the next line fo the function.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar (or maybe just related) problem trying to write a plugin, so I would like to leave a suggestion here for anyone who is interested.

My problem is that there are some very simple function I want to define, but since they are very simple, I want it to be defined in one line.  For example, here is a function to check whether a line number is valid:

```
function! ValidLine(line_number)
    return line_number>=1 && line_number<=line("$")
endfunction
```

This function is so simple that it does not need any documentation to explain, yet it has to take up 3 lines.  Of course, courtecy to previous answers, one can defined it this way:

```
exec "function! ValidLine(line_number) \n return line_number>=1 && line_number<=line('$') \n endfunction"
```

But suddenly a simple function that needed no explination is now a long string (without syntax highlighting) that is unreadable.

My solution is to use Vim's lambda expressions.  So the function would look like this:

```
let valid_line = { line_number -> line_number>=1 && line_number<=line('$') }
```

Now you have a function reference `valid_line` (notice that it need not be capitalized) that can be used just like any normal function.  Not only is it defined in one line, it is much more concise in syntax as well.